# Navigation menu fade in on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm designing a website and I'd like the navigation menu to fade in once I scroll down >50px. I'm using the following JavaScript with JQuery library:

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
                $('.menu').fadeIn(500);
            } else {
                $('.menu').fadeOut(500);
            }
        });

    });
})(jQuery);
```

The class `.menu` is set on `{display: none;}`.

Comment: You haven't defined `$(this)` for a start.

Comment: You forgot to tell us what's going wrong.

Comment: I'm presuming it isn't working...LOL

Comment: @Paulie_D...you are correct the menu doesn't fade in but what do you mean with defining $(this)?

Comment: it seems to work fine http://jsfiddle.net/rYQ5x/

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
       var distance = 50;
             if ($(window).scrollTop() > distance) {
                 $('nav').fadeIn(500);
             }
             else {
                 $('nav').fadeOut(500);
             }
        });
    });
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/1f676646da86292cecf8a5afe9c4af78)

Comment: Clearly works in the Codepen. If you can't get it, perhaps you could make your own example and show us the issue.

Comment: it does and it's exactly what i was looking for...I tried with embedding it in a <script> in the head or in a new .js file but on my website doesn't work

Comment: Have you added JQuery **before** the script?

Comment: I did, I have to admit that my website has more than one JQuery...like slideshows etc...

Comment: So...looks like it's something else going on then. Perhaps it's the order of your scripts.

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me.

Your .menu is probably at the top of a page and when you scroll you can't see it.

Add to test:

```
.menu {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10000; //just to check if it is behind the content
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/b2rrJ/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
            $('.menu').fadeIn(1000);
        } else {
            $('.menu').fadeOut(1000);
        }
    });
});
```

Just corrected your code! It works fine!